# Nested Arrays inside an object, searching with For loop, giving undefined result

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested, javascript-objects

I have editted to upload the complete code to run in any browser. All I'm getting is blanks here, but I am looking for every combination of numbers in groups of 3 from 1-80 (of which there are 82,160 combinations) and I want it to output an array of all of those results. However currently, the array is blank, but if I use my original code which includes a jQuery, it only gives me the last value, 78,79,and 80, over and over again 82160 times. It's giving me the right NUMBER of values, but it isn't filling those values correctly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Keno Tracker v2</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}
div {
    margin: 0em auto;
    padding: 00px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0em;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #38488f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    div {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 0em;
    }
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="mypanel" style="" id="Heading">Last Draw Result</div>
<div class="mypanel" style="all: unset" id="draw"></div><br>
<div class="mypanel" style="all: unset" id="numbs"></div><br>
<div class="mypanel" style="all: unset" id="bon"></div><br>
<div class="mypanel" style="" id="MostDue">Most Overdue Pairs</div>
<div class="mypanel" style="all: unset" id="mosdu"></div><br>
<div class="mypanel" style="" id="MostFreq">Most Frequent Pairs</div>
<div class="mypanel" style="all: unset" id="mosfq"></div><br>
<div class="mypanel" style="display:none" id="test"></div><br>
<div class="mypanel" style="display:none" id="test2"></div><br>
  <script type=text/javascript>
  var results = new Object();
    results.Num = [12354, 12353, 12352, 12351, 12350, 12349, 12348, 12347, 12346, 12345]
    results.Picks = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 38, 39, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 34, 12, 77], [5, 2, 4, 38, 39, 7, 8, 9, 18, 14, 23, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 34, 12, 77], [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 26, 21, 63, 41, 67, 71, 38, 39, 79, 32, 17, 72], [11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 13, 15, 26, 27, 61, 43, 62, 72, 79, 38, 39, 37, 10, 74], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 38, 39, 34, 12, 77], [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 14, 16, 23, 26, 67, 45, 66, 76, 1, 38, 39, 35, 13, 78], [10, 22, 19, 1, 8, 9, 37, 4, 11, 5, 20, 14, 3, 35, 38, 39, 41, 74, 57, 61], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 38, 39, 34, 12, 77], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 38, 39, 34, 12, 77], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 38, 39, 34, 12, 77]]
    results.Bonus = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
  var Totals = new Array();
  var temp = new Object();
  var drawsdone = 0
  var Totsdone = 0
  var displayd = 0
function getdraws() {
  var results = new Object()
     results.Num = [12354, 12353, 12352, 12351, 12350, 12349, 12348, 12347, 12346, 12345]
     results.Picks = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 38, 39, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 34, 12, 77], [5, 2, 4, 38, 39, 7, 8, 9, 18, 14, 23, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 34, 12, 77], [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 26, 21, 63, 41, 67, 71, 38, 39, 79, 32, 17, 72], [11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 13, 15, 26, 27, 61, 43, 62, 72, 79, 38, 39, 37, 10, 74], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 38, 39, 34, 12, 77], [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 14, 16, 23, 26, 67, 45, 66, 76, 1, 38, 39, 35, 13, 78], [10, 22, 19, 1, 8, 9, 37, 4, 11, 5, 20, 14, 3, 35, 38, 39, 41, 74, 57, 61], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 38, 39, 34, 12, 77], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 38, 39, 34, 12, 77], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15, 22, 25, 65, 44, 66, 75, 80, 38, 39, 34, 12, 77]]
     results.Bonus = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
window.drawsdone = 1
}
function getTotals() {
  if (Totsdone == 0){
    for (a=1;a<81;a++){
      for (b=1;b<81;b++){
        if (a<b){
          for (c=1;c<81;c++){
            if (b<c){
              temp.n1 = 0
              temp.n2 = 0
              temp.n3 = 0
              temp.fq123 = 0
              temp.sin123 = 0
              temp.fq12 = 0
              temp.sin12 = 0
              temp.fq13 = 0
              temp.sin13 = 0
              temp.fq23 = 0
              temp.sin23 = 0
              temp.fq1 = 0
              temp.sin1 = 0
              temp.fq2 = 0
              temp.sin2 = 0
              temp.fq3 = 0
              temp.sin3 = 0
              for (i in results.Picks){
                if (results.Picks[i].includes(a)){
                  if (results.Picks[i].includes(b)){
                    if (results.Picks[i].includes(c)){
                      if (temp.sin123 == 0){
                        temp.sin123 = results.Num[0]-results.Num[i]
                      }
                      temp.fq123++
                      temp.n1=a
                      temp.n2=b
                      temp.n3=c
                      }
                    }
                  }
              }
              Totals.push(temp)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    window.Totsdone = 1
  }
}
function display(){
  if (displayd == 0){
    console.log(Totals)
    Totals = new Array()
    window.displayd = 1
  }
}
getdraws();
setInterval(function(){
  getTotals()},2000)
setInterval(function(){
    display()},3000)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The length of your `Picks` array is 10, but you let `i` go beyond 9, so `Picks[i]` will be undefined when `i` is 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your for-loop has a hardcoded second condition of `i<20` and your Picks array only has 10 items, e.g. from the 11th item onwards you'll get `undefined`...

EDIT: Updated answer based on the updated question.

Still not sure about the entire logic of your code, but regarding

> I am looking for every combination of numbers in groups of 3 from 1-80 (of which there are 82,160 combinations) and I want it to output an array of all of those results.

I think this might be a more elegant solution:

```js
function* generateDraws(pool, size) { 
 if (size < 1) {
  yield [];
 } else {
  for (let i = size; i <= pool; i++) {
   for (let tail of generateDraws(i - 1, size - 1)) {
    tail.push(i);
    yield tail;
   }
  } 
 }
}

let draws = [];

for (let draw of generateDraws(80, 3)) {
 draws.push(draw);
}

console.log(draws.length);
//console.log(draws); // will not work in stackoverflow snippet runner, does in the browser though!
```

When dealing with large iterations like that (as you say, it's 82160 combinations, e.g. `80!/(3!(80-3)!`) things have a potential get quite slow, so using a generator function seems to be most appropriate as it will run with constant memory usage.

also be aware that generator functions are modern JS, so if you actually need to run this code client side and your users use old browser you need to transpile it with babel or typescript first OR generate the draws server-side and fetch them in your app from the server.

hope it helps at least a bit!

Comment: That worked for this snippet of code, but I can't seem to get it to work in my main block of code. Still coming up undefined even though the range of i is way below the range of the array..

Comment: The question is why you actually hardcode these ranges instead of using `<Array>.length-1` to determine the loop condition?

Comment: That gives an undefined result too.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to refactor that code into multiple blocks/functions, it's not really clear what it is supposed to do anyways =)...maybe you could improve your posted code as a code-snippet that can be executed?

Comment: the only way I could make it executable is to post the whole thing